# JMeter Distributed Testing java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (No such file or directory)

Tags: ssl, jmeter

setting up a distributed test with Jmeter i ended up in this problem.
First of all i'm aware setting the jmeter.property **server.rmi.ssl.disable=true** is a **work around.**

Still i'd like to see if it is possible to use this rmi_keystore.jks. The Jmeter documentation
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html is clear enough about setting up the environment but doesn't mention at all how specify the path to the rmi_keystore.jks, or if this has to be the rmi_keystore.jks on the worker or the one in the controller.

I noticed if you do a test on your machine as worker and controller ( as this guy does https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ok8Cqc0wipk  ) setting the absolute path to the rmi_keystore.jks works.
**Ex.** server.rmi.ssl.truststore.file=C:\path\to\the\rmi_keystore.jks and server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file=C:\path\to\the\rmi_keystore.jks and.

But this doesn't work when controller has a different path to the rmi_keystore.jks then the worker.

**My question is** : how can I set the right jmeter properties **server.rmi.ssl.truststore.file** and **server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file** to resolve the FileNotFoundException? Stating that default values don't work?

thank you everyone

Answer (score 7):

You need to:

1. Generate the `rmi_keystore.jks` file on the master machine
2. Copy it to all the slaves

The default location (where JMeter looks for the file) is `rmi_keystore.jks`, to wit if you drop it to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation on master and slaves - JMeter will find it and start using.

The `server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file` property should be used if you want to customize the file name and/or location so if it is different you can either set slave-specific location via *user.properties* file or pass it via `-J` command-line argument.

If location is common for all the slaves and you want to override it in a single shot - provide it via `-G` command-line argument.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `create-rmi-keystore.bat` to generate the rmi_keystore.jks. You will find it under Bin folder.